# how to correctly store the address of a procedure in a register x86_64 nasm?

Tags: nasm, linker-errors

I want to store the address of a procedure in a register as follows :

```
extern  _printf

section .text

global _foo

_foo :
    mov     rax, [rel _printf]
    call    rax
    ret
```

but i get this error when compiling with a main written in C :

```
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _foo from procedure.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
final section layout:
    __TEXT/__text addr=0x100000E70, size=0x000000AD, fileOffset=0x00000E70, type=1
    __TEXT/__stubs addr=0x100000F1E, size=0x00000018, fileOffset=0x00000F1E, type=28
    __TEXT/__stub_helper addr=0x100000F38, size=0x00000038, fileOffset=0x00000F38, type=32
    __TEXT/__cstring addr=0x100000F70, size=0x00000036, fileOffset=0x00000F70, type=13
    __TEXT/__unwind_info addr=0x100000FA8, size=0x00000050, fileOffset=0x00000FA8, type=22
    __DATA/__nl_symbol_ptr addr=0x100001000, size=0x00000008, fileOffset=0x00001000, type=29
    __DATA/__got addr=0x100001008, size=0x00000010, fileOffset=0x00001008, type=29
    __DATA/__la_symbol_ptr addr=0x100001018, size=0x00000020, fileOffset=0x00001018, type=27
ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (-4294971162 max is +/-2GB): from _foo (0x100000F13) to _printf@0x00000000 (0x00000000) in '_foo' from procedure.o for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i tried compiling with -Wl,-no_pie and i got this :

```
ld: illegal text-relocation to '_printf' in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd from '_foo' in procedure.o for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so how could i resolve this problem ??

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to do this: static linking and dynamic linking.  I'll show both.  I suspect (based on your code) you are statically linking.

The first two sections are for Linux.  The last section is for Macs.

## Static Linking

The following works the way you want, I think.  I don't use `rel` because I don't need to; since `printf` is statically linked, I can just get its address directly.

The `push rbp` (8 bytes) is necessary; it makes sure the stack is 16-byte aligned after the return address (8 more bytes) is pushed by the call to `printf`.  Calling functions that may use the `xmm` registers requires that you have the stack aligned on a 16-byte boundary, or you can get a segfault, and `printf` uses those registers.

Also, `printf` expects the number of fp arguments to be in `rax`, so I set it to zero and use `rdx` instead to hold the address.

```
; hello-static.asm
; nasm -felf64 hello-static.asm && gcc -static -o hello-static hello-static.o

        extern  printf

        section .text

        global main

main:   push    rbp
        mov     rdx, printf
        mov     rdi, fmt
        xor     eax, eax
        call    rdx
        pop     rbp
        ret

fmt:    db "Hello", 10, 0
```

## Dynamic Linking

The traditional way to do this in a *dynamically linked* executable is via the PLT.  The following does it that way.

```
; hello.asm
; nasm -felf64 hello.asm && gcc -o hello hello.o

        extern  printf

        section .text

        global main

main:   push    rbp
        lea     rdx, [rel printf wrt ..plt]
        mov     rdi, fmt
        xor     eax, eax
        call    rdx
        pop     rbp
        ret

fmt:    db "Hello", 10, 0
```

A few words of explanation.  First, pushing `rbp` makes sure the stack is aligned on a 16-byte boundary by the call to `printf`.  Second, I used `rel` to get the address of the jump in the PLT with respect to the value of `rip`.  Third, I used `rdx` instead of `rax`; the latter register is used by `printf` for the number of floating point arguments.

The address in `rdx` will not contain the actual address of `printf`.  For that you would need to go to the GOT and fetch it from there.

The following code fetches the address from the GOT.

```
; hello-got.asm
; nasm -felf64 hello-got.asm && gcc -o hello-got hello-got.o

        extern  printf
        extern  _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_

        section .text

        global main

main:   push    rbx
        lea     rbx, [rel _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_]
        lea     rdx, [printf wrt ..got]
        add     rdx, rbx
        mov     rdx, [rdx]
        mov     rdi, fmt
        xor     eax, eax
        call    rdx
        pop     rbx
        ret

fmt:    db "Hello", 10, 0
```

Here I first get the address of the GOT using `rip`-relative addressing.  Then I get the *offset* into the GOT of the `printf` function's vector.  Then I add the offset to the base address of the GOT to get the absolute address of the `printf` vector.  Finally, I move the vector into `rdx` so I  can call it later.

I don't push `rbp` because I don't need to save the stack frame here; I have to preserve `rbx` (it is traditionally used to hold the base address of the GOT) because it's a callee-saved register, and that takes care of stack alignment.

## Mac (macho64)

The procedure for the Mac is nearly the same: look up the symbol in the global offset table to find the vector, and then de-reference it to obtain the actual address of the procedure.  Use `wrt ..gotpcrel` instead of finding the GOT and then using `wrt ..got`.

```
; hello-mac.asm
; nasm -fmacho64 hello-mac.asm && ld -o hello-mac hello-mac.o -lc

        extern _printf
        global _main

        section .text

_main:  push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     rdi, msg
        mov     rsi, 17
        lea     rsi, [rel _printf wrt ..gotpcrel]
        xor     eax, eax
        call    [rsi]
        xor     eax, eax
        leave
        ret

        section .data

msg:    db "printf: 0x%lx", 10, 0
```

Comment: the problem is, I'm working on MACOS so the ..got symbol is not defined. However it works fine on linux.

Comment: That's actually easier, oddly enough.  I'll edit my prior answer to address dynamic linking on a Mac.